# How can I detect the end of a webpage?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

How can I detect the end of a webpage to put a div bar that contains the 'about' and 'contact us' links? I want to detect the end of the page so the bar can automatically put itself at the end of the page regardless the resolution.     Thanks

Comment: What about wraping all contents with a table?

Comment: @myro i did it but the same problem it doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean with the end of the page regardless of the resolution?

Comment: @MartijnB whether the resolution is 800X600 or 1440X900 it should detect the end of the page without making a scroll and put the bar at the end

Comment: I think we all can agree to a unique solution, if you tell us how you intend to implement this. Using JS? or C#? Do you want to implement it in an off-line application or directly into the web page?

Comment: @PaulaShenouda how is this different from adding this directly to the end of your body in your page. It doesn't care if it's 800x600 or 1440x900 it's always at the bottom or are you adding it dynamically?

Comment: @IceCoder Thank you i found a solution.

Comment: @MartijnB Thank you i found a solution

Comment: If you found a solution then you should accept an answer; if none helped you then you should detail what solved your problem and then accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want implementation in pure JavaScript try:

```
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.innerHTML = "put html here";
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

[**Here**](http://jsbin.com/uxeviy/4/edit) is the jsbin snippet.

Another possible solution is:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "put html here";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a master page, or I guess since you tagged this with javascript you could use jquery as well.  Use a selector to select the body or html tag and then use append:
http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$("body").append("Your links");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can find the `</body>` tag, and add your code immediately before it, being sure it will be rendered at the very end of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.pageYOffstet + window.screen.height == document.height
```